# Minimize distance between the ships

Tags: calculus, derivatives

I'm studying calculus from a the book "Calculus with Analytic Geometry by Georfe F Simmons", and I have a certain difficulty to solve the following problem:

Ah noon the ship A is at a distance at north from a ship B, and going to south at velocity of 16 mi / h. The ship B is going to West at 12 mi / h. What is the moment that they will be nearest as possible, and what is the distance ?

My first idea is to use the following two formulas to represent the space where x is the time:

Ship A: $y = -16x+50$

Ship B: $y = 12x$

The formula to get the distance is: $d^2 = ((-16x+50) - 12x) + (y-0)^2$ (Pythagorean) , then to minimize the distance I need to derivate d.

I dont know how to find the answer after this. Can you help me to make it clearest ?
Thank you !

Comment: You do want to use the Pythagorean Theorem, where one side of the triangle is given by 50-16x (the distance from ship A to the original position of ship B) and the other is given by 12x (the distance ship B has traveled).

Comment: Yes, that is what I mean. The idea semms wrong ?

Comment: You should review your $d^2$ formula. Also, as $d\geq0$, minimizing $d^2$ is a lot easier.

Comment: This will give $d^2=(50-16x)^2+(12x)^2$, where x is the number of hours traveled.

Comment: Sorry but I do not understand yours formula. Can you be more specific ?

Comment: I guess you idea will find the distance between the vertices A and B of this triangle. Is it right ?!

Comment: Suggestions, let $t$ be time from noon. and draw a diagram.

Comment: André, I can see now. When t increse, the size of the edges will change too. So, the formula d²=(50−16x)²+(12x)² work fine, thinking  each equation give to me the location of each ship.

Comment: I have found the answers: At 2 P.M. the distance is minimium possible. And the distance is 30 mi. :)